# Turn off power saving mode on Seagate Expansion Drive with sdparm

Tags: hard-disk, external-hdd

I'm trying to see if there's a possibility to disable the power saving on my external Seagate Expansion Drive that is connected through USB to my NUC running Ubuntu Server. I had problems using `hdparm` as it gave me an error message, so I instead found `sdparm` that seemed to work for my particular drive according to [this post](https://superuser.com/a/1263447/640150).

I run `sudo sdparm -l -a /dev/sda` and get the following output:

```
    /dev/sda: Seagate   Expansion Desk    0915
    Direct access device specific parameters: WP=0  DPOFUA=0
Caching (SBC) [ca] mode page:
  IC            0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Initiator control
  ABPF          0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Abort pre-fetch
  CAP           0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Caching analysis permitted
  DISC          1  [cha: n, def:  1, sav:  1]  Discontinuity
  SIZE          0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Size enable
  WCE           1  [cha: y, def:  1, sav:  1]  Write cache enable
  MF            0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Multiplication factor
  RCD           0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Read cache disable
  DRRP          0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Demand read retention priority
  WRP           0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Write retention priority
  DPTL          -1  [cha: n, def: -1, sav: -1]  Disable pre-fetch transfer length
  MIPF          0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Minimum pre-fetch
  MAPF          -1  [cha: n, def: -1, sav: -1]  Maximum pre-fetch
  MAPFC         -1  [cha: n, def: -1, sav: -1]  Maximum pre-fetch ceiling
  FSW           0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Force sequential write
  LBCSS         0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Logical block cache segment size
  DRA           0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Disable read ahead
  SYNC_PROG     0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Synchronous cache progress indication
  NV_DIS        0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Non-volatile cache disable
  NCS           255  [cha: n, def:255, sav:255]  Number of cache segments
  CSS           0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Cache segment size
Control [co] mode page:
  TST           0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Task set type
  TMF_ONLY      0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Task management functions only
  DPICZ         0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Disable protection information check if protect field zero
  D_SENSE       0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Descriptor format sense data
  GLTSD         0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Global logging target save disable
  RLEC          0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Report log exception condition
  QAM           1  [cha: n, def:  1, sav:  1]  Queue algorithm modifier
  NUAR          0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  No unit attention on release
  QERR          0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Queue error management
  RAC           0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Report a check
  UA_INTLCK     0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Unit attention interlocks control
  SWP           0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Software write protect
  ATO           0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Application tag owner
  TAS           0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Task aborted status
  ATMPE         0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Application tag mode page enabled
  RWWP          0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Reject write without protection
  SBLP          0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Supported block lengths and protection information
  AUTOLOAD      0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Autoload mode
  BTP           0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Busy timeout period (100us)
  ESTCT         0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Extended self test completion time (sec)
Power condition [po] mode page:
  PM_BG         0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Power management, background functions, precedence
  STANDBY_Y     0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Standby_y timer enable
  IDLE_C        0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Idle_c timer enable
  IDLE_B        0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Idle_b timer enable
  IDLE          0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Idle_a timer enable
  STANDBY       0  [cha: y, def:  1, sav:  0]  Standby_z timer enable
  ICT           0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Idle_a condition timer (100 ms)
  SCT           4294967286  [cha: y, def:9000, sav:4294967286]  Standby_z condition timer (100 ms)
  IBCT          0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Idle_b condition timer (100 ms)
  ICCT          0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Idle_c condition timer (100 ms)
  SYCT          0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Standby_y condition timer (100 ms)
  CCF_IDLE      0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  check condition on transition from idle
  CCF_STAND     0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  check condition on transition from standby
  CCF_STOPP     0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  check condition on transition from stopped
```

I'm very novice to the terminology around HDD's, but my guess is that `STANDBY` would be a boolean for if the drive should run in standby-mode? Would turning this to `1` instead of `0` tell the disk to not "fall asleep" or is it the opposite?

Are there any other settings in the list that I should take a look at or am I doing this completely wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I recently stumbled upon wanting an answer to the same question. I for one have a couple of WD My Book 25ED that go into sleep mode even in midst of write operations. Anyway, after some research I wrote a script, `sdparm-disable_sleep.sh`, which, when executed, solved my problem:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: sdparm-disable_sleep.sh <device>
[[ -n "${1}" && -b "${1}" ]] \
  && sdparm --flexible --page=po -l -a "${1}" \
  && { sdparm --flexible --set=STANDBY_Z=0 -S "${1}" \
       && sdparm --flexible --page=po -l -a "${1}"; }
```

In essence, it is the `sdparm --set=STANDBY_Z=0 -S <device>` command that sets the `STANDBY_Z` to `0`, thereby disabling the timer, and saves that setting.

In your case the parameter seems to be named just `STANDBY`, and according to your pasted output it is already disabled (because the saved value is `0`). Perhaps the firmware is buggy, and I'd try to issue the command anyway - maybe without `-S` - and see whether that sticks until a drive reboot/re-init at least.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I see that I also have a parameter called `SCT` that seems to stand for "Standby_z condition timer (100 ms)". Not sure what this is, but could it be some kind of timer that sets it to sleep mode after a couple of 100 ms?

Comment: As far as I've gathered, the SCT parameter determines the idle time needed for the device to enter standby mode, but should only come into play if the STANDBY parameter is enabled.

Comment: For my sleeping-on-the-job WD My Passport 25E2  4005 .......... running $ sudo sdparm -la <device> ......... included "STANDBY       1  [cha: y, def:  1, sav:  1]  Standby_z timer enable" .......... and after $ sudo sdparm --set=STANDBY=0 -S <device> ....... is now "STANDBY       0  [cha: y, def:  1, sav:  0]  Standby_z timer enable" ........ which is good.

Comment: And, same for a "WD My Passport 0741  1022".